# Socket.io client-side causing high CPU usage

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am running a simple websocket chat application in NodeJS and socket.io and when connected to the server from a browser, the CPU usage on the client machine goes up easily 10x...

How would I go about debugging CPU usage on the client side?

Thanks,

Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops! turns out this was because the chat was getting filled up with messages that were each updating a relative date every 3seconds. Solution: delete oldest messages from the DOM to stop date updating 100's of messages every few seconds :D